# "use" keyword/word in Ruby/Rails/Rack code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, rack-middleware

Recently I happened to see this word in Ruby code, `use`, when I was going through some code related to [goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath), middleware etc. Looks like it is different from `include`/`extend`, and `require`.

Can somebody explain why this `use` keyword exists, and how it is different from `include`/`require`? How does it work, when to use it?

Comment: `use` is *not* part of standard Ruby (and [it is *not* a keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/)). Where did it come from?

Comment: check out [this](http://confreaks.com/videos/961-mwrc2012-rack-middleware-as-a-general-purpose-abstraction), and [this](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/wiki/Middleware), I thought a keyword like thing it is

Comment: Not the most intuitive of rdocs, but "ruby rack api" (and then scrolling the methods to find `use`) resulted in [this link](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Builder.html#M000171). Note how it is just a method. This is probably discussed further in other Rack documentation/guides. (Updating the title/question with new information/context will likely lead to more focused -- and relevant -- responses.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### The Documentation

As people have pointed out, `use` is not a Ruby keyword, it is in fact a method of the [`Rack::Builder` class](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Builder.html#method-i-use):

> **`use(middleware, *args, &block)`**
>
> Specifies middleware to use in a stack.

[This documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Builder.html) ([pointed out by @user166390](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982310/use-keyword-word-in-ruby-code/22245277#comment15976209_11982310)) describes it like this:

> `Rack::Builder` implements a small DSL to iteratively construct `Rack` applications.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> app = Rack::Builder.new {
>   use Rack::CommonLogger
>   use Rack::ShowExceptions
>   map "/lobster" do
>     use Rack::Lint
>     run Rack::Lobster.new
>   end
> }
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> app = Rack::Builder.app do
>   use Rack::CommonLogger
>   lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, 'OK'] }
> end
> ```
>
> `use` adds a middleware to the stack, `run` dispatches to an application.

### The Source Code

I'm not too familiar with the [`Rack::Builder` source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb), but it looks like each time you call `use` with a new middleware module, it gets added to an array, and each module is run/injected in the reverse order in which it was added (last-in-first-out order, a.k.a. stack order). The result of running the previous middleware is passed to the next middleware in the stack via [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

1. [Lines 53-56](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb#L53-L56):

   ```
   def initialize(default_app = nil,&block)
     # @use is parallel assigned to [].
     @use, @map, @run = [], nil, default_app
     instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
   end
   ```
2. [Lines 81-87](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb#L81-L87):

   ```
   def use(middleware, *args, &block)
     if @map
       mapping, @map = @map, nil
       @use << proc { |app| generate_map app, mapping }
     end
     # The new middleware is added to the @use array.
     @use << proc { |app| middleware.new(app, *args, &block) }
   end
   ```
3. [Lines 131-135](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb#L131-L135):

   ```
   def to_app
     app = @map ? generate_map(@run, @map) : @run
     fail "missing run or map statement" unless app
     # The middlewares are injected in reverse order.
     @use.reverse.inject(app) { |a,e| e[a] }
   end
   ```

### Additional resources

1. [A Quick Introduction to Rack](http://rubylearning.com/blog/a-quick-introduction-to-rack/#C16).
2. [Ruby on Rack #2 - The Builder](http://m.onkey.org/ruby-on-rack-2-the-builder).

Comment: First link is dead. Alternate: http://rubylearning.com/blog/2013/04/02/whats-rack/