# Why is "app.Add*()" and "app.Use*()" naming convention used in ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: node.js, express, asp.net-core, .net-core, naming-conventions

In ASP.NET Core, when configuring services I notice that it's usually done by extension methods that have prefix `Add*`.
Similarly, when configuring middleware pipeline, we have extension methods with `Use*` prefix.

For example when adding the authentication services:

`services.AddAuthentication("MyAuthService")`

And then we add the `Authentication middleware` in the pipeline (which will use the `Authentication services` that we just added above) like this:

`app.UseAuthentication();`

So I have few questions:

- What is the logic behind this naming convention? Where does it come from?
- When I see this code, how should I read it in my head?
- Why is `Add` not used when adding middleware to the pipeline rather than `Use`? Wouldn't it be more logical that we also use `Add` prefix because we are also *adding* a middleware to the pipeline? (at least to me that would make a bit more sense than `Use middleware`).

I noticed similar convention is used in NodeJs Express web apps, but I am not very familiar with Express. Is ASP.NET Core inspired by it or is it vice versa?

Is this convention also used in other web server frameworks (eg. for python, java, php, ruby on rails etc.)?

Comment: I agree with Rafi, and you may also take a look at the sample of how to [set cors policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware-1) in asp.net core, it has the same logic which add policy first then use the policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actions we take are described by the terms **Add** and **Use**, respectively:

The term "**Add**" refers to the act of adding services to the application, **however this does not imply that they will be used** - "Add" implies an action **without any direct consequences**.

The term "**Use**" refers to the act of **actually using** them in your application (as they have already been added) - the term "Use" implies an **action with consequences**.

Your authentication example clearly shows the logic described above:

**AddAuthentication** - Registers services required by authentication services (the authentication process would not take place unless you actually use these registered services in the application pipeline)

**UseAuthentication** - Adds the AuthenticationMiddleware to the specified IApplicationBuilder, which **enables** authentication capabilities.

Comment: Good answer :). For more history, Use* came from the Katana/OWIN days which stole that convention from ruby's rack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982310/use-keyword-word-in-ruby-rails-rack-code.

Use is also pretty standard across multiple language stacks for this purpose...